# Disable notifications during a call on iPhone 5 iOS 8.3

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, call, vibrate

While I am talking on the phone, I often receive messages on Telegram or WhatsApp, or other notifications. And when I receive them they arrive in bursts, which is really annoying.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour? **How do I disable notifications only when I’m talking?**

iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (at least on a non-jailbroken phone).

You can use Do Not Disturb, but you have to set it ahead of time so that it applies even while the phone is unlocked, and then toggle it on at the start of the call, and toggle it off at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Go to notifications in settings and then turn off banners and sounds for those specific app notifications. The only way they should notify you is with the red app badge number.

If you want no notifications from the app, just turn it off.
Do Not Disturb is also useful to set up.